# Heredoc and Adobe Dreamweaver 2019 CC

Tags: dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver 2015 CC there was this "hack", adding the following lines to

```
C:>Program Files>Adobe>Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015>Configuration>CodeColoring>PHP.xml
```

that added Heredoc code coloring

```
<blockStart doctypes="PHP_MySQL" scheme="customText"><![CDATA[<?php\s]]></blockStart>
<blockEnd><![CDATA[<<<EOM]]></blockEnd>
<blockStart doctypes="PHP_MySQL" scheme="customText"><![CDATA[<?php\n]]></blockStart>
<blockEnd><![CDATA[<<<EOM]]></blockEnd>
<blockStart doctypes="PHP_MySQL" scheme="customText"><![CDATA[EOM;]]></blockStart>
<blockEnd><![CDATA[?>]]></blockEnd>
```

In Dreamweaver 2019 CC, that I had the chance to give a try during the weekend, the "hack" doesn't work anymore. Is there any alternative method for adding HTML code coloring inside a Heredoc?

Initially, I suspected the new tag libraries feature might be the key to my problem, but after studying it a little, I think the solution to my problem is hidden elsewhere...